# ThinkPad P50 2016 shuts down using graphic demanding software

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, thinkpad

I ran into some heat issues with my p50 this day.
Its a Ubuntu system.

Its pretty hot here atm ~35°C, but when i run a Game e.g. Dota 2 on high settings the laptop shuts down after 3-5 min.

When playing with lowest resolution settings its fine (but ugly)

I can hear both fans are working and i do not experience any fps drops so there is no throtteling.

When compiling my programs my machine sometimes runs full occupied on all 8 Cores and there is no heat issue so i guess its the grafic-card.

Is there anything i can do?

Comment: The current P50 modelo comes with a Nvidia Quadro M1000M or M2000. Yours probably have a similar but older Nvidia. You need to install Nvidia drivers, of course.

Comment: It is a M1000M, but i  installed the nvidia driver already cause i use the gpu for training small keras models.

Comment: Which graphics card model and which driver version?

Comment: when checking software updater it says:
GM107GLM[Quadro M1000M]

Comment: and "Using Nvidia driver metapackage nvidia driver-390